# Javascript TypeError: $(...).parent is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having this error when I click on the following code:

```
onclick="tester.removeit(this);"
```

I get Error:

```
TypeError: $(...).parent is not a function
```

Here is the function:

```
removeit: function(ele) {

    $(ele).parent('div').fadeOut();
    console.log(this);

},
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: have you given the reference to jQuery? If you are loading jQuery from CDN, make sure you are online

Comment: before the `.parent` section, add a `console.log(ele);` I think `ele` is not a jQuery object.

Comment: Working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/ge1Lwtr6/ And if the question is about `this`, _"The value of `this` depends on how function is called!"_

Comment: Sounds like you're including some other library (like PrototypeJS or MooTools), not jQuery. (If you weren't including anything, the error would be complaining about `$`, not `parent`.)

Comment: Spot on! It was a library conflict with jQuery. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a library conflict, where you're including PrototypeJS or MooTools after including jQuery.

When you do that, only one library can use `$` as its main identifier. You can tell jQuery to "release" `$` via [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict):

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script src="prototypejs.js"></script>
```

Then in code where you want to use jQuery, use `jQuery` rather than `$`:

```
// ...
removeit: function(ele) {

    jQuery(ele).parent('div').fadeOut();
    console.log(this);

},
// ...
```

Or wrap all of your code using jQuery in an IIFE that accepts `$` as an arg:

```
(function($) {
    // ...
    removeit: function(ele) {

        $(ele).parent('div').fadeOut();
        console.log(this);

    },
    // ...
})(jQuery);
```